# uiwebview nor reading css file or image

Tags: html, ios, css, uiwebview

i have a web view that successfully displays a local html file. The css file and imgage are in the same folder as the html file and the app files.
I've tried three different methods to display the html, but none show the css or image. The image is represented by a small square with a question mark.

this  is the loading function

```
func loadPage() {
// 1st try
// if let htmlFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(page, ofType: "html"){
//let htmlData = NSData(contentsOfFile: htmlFile)
//let baseURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath)

// webView.loadData(htmlData, MIMEType: "text/html", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: baseURL)

// 2nd try - - - - - - -
//  let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(page, withExtension: "html");
//let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!);
//webView.loadRequest(myRequest);

var testHTML = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(page, ofType: "html")
var contents = NSString(contentsOfFile: testHTML!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
var baseUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: testHTML!) //for load css file

webView.loadHTMLString(contents, baseURL: baseUrl)



//}
}
```

The html is

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bg.css" type="text/css">


<h1>1 ornano car park</h1>
<p class= "test"> At the end of the coach park there's a circle where coaches can turn. From there turn your back on the cathedral and go towards the river.</p>
<img src="board.jpg">
```

If I put the style in the file, it works but I want to have 20 HTML pages so I want to use a css file.

To try to understand what's happening I added a println() to show the path.

```
var testHTML = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(page, ofType: "html")
println(testHTML)
var testCSS = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("bg", ofType: "css")
println(testCSS)
```

Which prints

```
   Optional("/Users/colinmcgarry/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7BAEC0D1-5942-4D60-AD4F-CCFF4C70BB0B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/42AAF91D-8477-428A-AEC6-950D89846C80/TestWebView2.app/1page.html")
nil
```

The bg.css file is in the same folder as the html files and is in the list off files in the app. Doesn't seem to exist for xcode.

Comment: Oddly, your question provided the answer by correctly and succinctly describing everything that needs to happen. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
I've been experimenting with targets. The files weren't in the active target. 
Printing the path led me to realise that I had TestWebView2 as a Target. 
keep a clear head.